# Вопрос по Apache (.htaccess RewriteRule)

Tags: .htaccess, apache, mod-rewrite

Один сайт имеет разные содержимое и отображается в своем языке для каждого домена, вопрос в том, что переадресация не работает, не могу понять в чем ошибка, как сделать так, чтобы каждый домен переключал без 'www' на 'www' и загружался нужный домен, а не какой-то один.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} сайт.com.ua$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.сайт.com.ua/$1 [L,R=301] 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} сайт.ru$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.сайт.ru/$1 [L,R=301] 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} сайт.pl$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.сайт.pl/$1 [L,R=301] 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} сайт.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.сайт.com/$1 [L,R=301] 


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^www].*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Вот такое нашлось решение этого вопроса для всех адресов, без кучи записей лишних.